# Join two columns in a Dataframe that has been pivoted

Tags: python, pandas, join, dataframe, pivot

I have two columns I am trying to join (Year and Quarter). I have pulled the data from sql and pivoted it as seen below:

```
df3 = pd.pivot_table(df, index=["Year", "Q"], columns='Area', values="Lows", aggfunc=np.sum, fill_value=0)
```

I would now like to join the columns `Year` and `Q` together for charting purposes but my indexes seem to be messed up. Below is how the dataframe is displayed.

```
Before:
Year   Q
2003   1
       2
       3
       4
2004   1
       2

Desired output:
Period 
2003 1
2003 2
2003 3
2003 4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
df3.index = df3.index.to_series().apply(lambda x: ' '.join([str(y) for y in x]))
```

***more generalized***

```
join = lambda x, delim=' ': delim.join([str(y) for y in x])

df3.index = df3.index.to_series().apply(join, delim=' ')
```

Comment: I am not sure what that did as my year and quarter columns have been deleted and now i have one new column filled with "NaN" all the way down

Comment: @spacedinosaur10 I neglected that these were integers.  I've fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Another faster solutions:

```
df.index = ['{} {}'.format(idx[1], idx[0]) for idx in df.index]
```

and

```
df.index = [' '.join((str(idx[0]), str(idx[1]))) for idx in df.index]
```

**Timings**:

```
In [190]: %timeit df.index.to_series().apply(lambda x: ' '.join([str(y) for y in x]))
10 loops, best of 3: 44.5 ms per loop

In [191]: %timeit [' '.join((str(idx[0]), str(idx[1]))) for idx in df.index]
10 loops, best of 3: 26.6 ms per loop

In [192]: %timeit ['{} {}'.format(idx[1], idx[0]) for idx in df.index]
100 loops, best of 3: 19.2 ms per loop
```

**Code for timings**:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[2,2,2,1,7,2],
                   'B':[5,5,5,4,7,4],
                   'C':[7,8,9,4,8,1]})

df = df.groupby(['A','B']).sum()
df = pd.concat([df]*10000)
print (df)
```

Comment: @piRSquared this was very helpful , thank you. Is there a way I can give the new joined column a name? So i can call it when graphing?

Comment: I created a new column called 'Period' by setting df3.index = df3['Period'] which works for my needs. But it would be nice to know if i could someone rename that joined row

Comment: You can use `df3 = df3.rename(columns={'Period':'newname'})` if need rename column name. If need reset index use `df3 = df3.reset_index()`